# Why do comaximal ideals in $\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ determine disjoint varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider two ideals $I$ and $J$ of $\mathbb{k}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$. They are called *comaximal* if $I+J = \mathbb{k}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$.

For $k = \mathbb{C}$, the above definition is $\iff$ $\mathbb{V}(I) \cap \mathbb{V}(J) = \emptyset$.

Why?

If $I+J = \mathbb{C}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$, then that means there is some $a \in I$ and $b \in J$ such that $a+b = 1 \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \cdots , x_n]$. But what information does this tell me about the varities of $I$ and $J$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\Bbb V(I)\cap \Bbb V(J)=\Bbb V(I+J)$. By Nullstellensatz, we obtain that $$\Bbb V(I)\cap\Bbb V(J)=\Bbb V(1)=\emptyset\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{I+J}=(1)$$

Now, the radical of an ideal is $(1)$ if and only if the ideal itself is $(1)$, thus proving that $\Bbb V(I)\cap \Bbb V(J)=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $I+J=(1)$ for $\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$.